# Image as a link laid out in flexbox

Tags: css, image, flexbox

I’m trying to achieve images that are links and laid out using flexbox.

My images look great when they’re not links:

HTML:

```
<div class="flexbox">
        <img class="image1" src="img/image1.png" alt="A cool image">
        <img class="image2" src="img/image2.png" alt="An even cooler image">
```

CSS:

```
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

But when I make the images links, I lose all the benefits of my flexbox layout:

HTML:

```
<div class="flexbox">
        <a href="sunrise.html">
<img class="image1" src="img/image1.png" alt="A cool image">
</a>
        <a href=”sunset.html”>
<img class="image2" src="img/image2.png" alt="An even cooler image">
</a>
    </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem you are getting?

Comment: I'm losing the "space-between" feature, and my images lose their class formatting :(

Comment: I am getting the same output in both cases. Could you link to jsfiddle where I can see where the output you get is going wrong

Comment: I got the same output in both cases, too, in jsfiddle, but not in my actual code. Not to worry, Abhishek - I'll look more closely at my actual code as the jsfiddle shows that I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: You can check the below answer as well. I tried all flex-properties and I get the expected result in each one

Answer (score 0):

I can see the code working in both cases. You can see below that I have 2 rows of image and in each of them, the flex-box is working as expected.

```css
.flexbox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.separator {
  height: 10px;
  margin: 30px;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexbox">
  <a href=”sunset.html”><img class="image1" height='150px' src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="A cool image">
    <a>
      <a href="/"><img class="image2" height="150px" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" alt="An even cooler image"></a>
</div>

<div class="separator"></div>

<div class="flexbox">
  <img class="image1" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" height="150px" alt="A cool image">
  <img class="image2" src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_trulli.jpg" height="150px" alt="An even cooler image">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

since this question is more than a year old, I suppose the issue has already been sorted out. However, I just had the exact same problem and figured it out for myself, so I thought this might come in handy for some (please bear with me since I'm new into HTML/CSS):

I build a small gallery website and I wanted to link the image on the main page to subpages. However, when I added the the `<a href>`-tag to my images, the formatting would be all over the place. I sorted this out by using **flex-grow: 1** in CSS for my images (and another `<div>`-element) and for the a-tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can give the same class to img elements and a elements

```css
.flexbox img{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}

.flexbox a{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0; 
}
```

This worked for me in a similar case