# Can't center images using align-items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I can't get flexbox or even CSS in general to work on an image acting as a link.
All I wanted was to use flexbox to move an image to the right side of the screen.

Here is all the relevant HTML:

```
<body>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red; display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
    <a style="align-self: flex-end; margin-left: auto;" href="index.html">
      <img style="width: 15%; margin-left: auto;" class="arrows" id="pointRightArrow" 
      src="../Images/ArrowImg.png"
      alt="black arrow pointing right" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

I also found a guy that had the exact same problem as I am having [Image as a link laid out in flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62840386/image-as-a-link-laid-out-in-flexbox), but the solution given didn't work for me, in fact, it literally did nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the flex on the `a` so it will be the parent container for the flexed items (the image).

```html
<body>
  <div style="border: 2px solid red; ">
    <a href="" style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end;">
      <img style="width: 15%;" class="arrows" id="pointRightArrow" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
    </a>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the rules only in div, if you set rule positions in `div`, `a` and `img` there will be conflicts.

Use in div:

- `display:flex` to flex element
- `align-items:center` to center elements vertically
- `justify-content: flex-end` to align elements from right

Answer (score 0):

First Thing you want to do is change the setting in `<div>` only;

- Type in `display:flex;` then,
- `align-items:center;` then lastly,
- `justify-content: flex-end;`

This should work.